# 'Color' to expected argument type 'UIColor?'

Tags: ios, iphone, colors, swiftui

I was trying to change the color with the extension it gives an error.[image: Error screen]
How to we can fix this error.

I write extension as follows.

```
extension Color{
    static let enqueOrange = Color("Organgecolor")
}
```

Calenderview code:

```
struct CalendarView: View {
    var number : String
    var days : String
    var color : UIColor
    var textcolor : UIColor
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(self.number)
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
            Text(self.days)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
        }.padding([.top,.bottom], 10)
            .padding([.leading,.trailing],10)
            .background(Color(self.color))
            .cornerRadius(30)
    }
}
```

Comment: Either make CalendarView's `color` property take in a `Color` (not `UIColor`), or do `UIColor(self.days......)`

Comment: Gives error unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `CalendarView` accepts `UIColor` as a parameter. If it is a custom view you can change the custom views propery `color: UIColor` to `color: Color`, or you can change your

```
color: self.days[i].isToday? Color.enqueOrange : .white
```

to

```
color: self.days[i].isToday? UIColor(Color.enqueOrange) : UIColor(.white)
```

Comment: Gives error unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

Comment: Can i get the code for your `CalendarView`?

Comment: The code you provided works fine on my end. You could try changing `var color : Color` in `CalendarView`